# Why am I not seeing any result PHP mysqli prepare

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php  
    include "connection.php";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['q'])){
         
    $INTHECART = array();
    include "connection.php";
  
     $result = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `laptop` WHERE id_no=?");
     $result->bind_param("i",$_REQUEST['q']);
     $result->execute();

    $dirToImg = "img/";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $product_id = $row['id_no'];
            $laptopName = $row["laptopName"] ;
            $laptopImage = $row["laptopImages"];
            $laptopFrontImage = $row["laptopFrontImages"]; 
            $laptopFeatures = $row["laptopFeatures"]; 
            $laptopOrginalPrice = $row["laptopPriceOrginal"] ;
            $laptopDiscountPrice  = $row["laptopPriceDiscounted"]; 
            $n =  $row["laptopRating"];
            if($_REQUEST['q']==$product_id){

            ?>
        <div class="container">
        <input type="text" hidden style="display: none;" data-id="<?php echo $product_id;   ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo "{$dirToImg}{$laptopFrontImage}" ;?>">
        <div class="btm">
            <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $laptopName ; ?></h2>
         <small>
            <?php
            while ($n>0){
                echo("⭐");
                $n = $n-1;
            }
    echo "inside if";

            ?>
         </small>
         <small class="orginal_price">
             <small class="high_price">
               RS.  <?php echo $laptopOrginalPrice ; ?>
            </small>
            RS. <?php echo  $laptopDiscountPrice ; ?>
            </small>
            <br>
                
    <?php
            // making a query to check fetch the data from the userinfo tab.
            if(isset($_SESSION["is_login"])){
                $checkQ = "SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE emailAddress='{$_SESSION['email']}'";
            //    checking the output of the query
                $output =  $connection->query($checkQ);
                if($output->num_rows > 0){
                    // echo "it has some value";
                  
                    while($cart = $output->fetch_assoc()){
                        array_push($INTHECART , $cart['cart']);
                    }
                    $unique_array_IN  = array_unique($INTHECART);
                    
                         if(in_array($product_id, $unique_array_IN) ){
                          
                                ?>
                                
                                <a class="btn_add_cart disabled " href="#cart">
                                    In the Cart <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                                <?php
                        }
                        else {
                            ?>
                            <a class="btn_add_cart " href="#cart">
                                        Add to cart <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                    }}
                    else {
                        ?>
                        <a class="btn_add_cart " href="#cart">
                                    Add to cart <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                        <?php
                    }}
                    else{
                        ?>
                        <a class="btn_add_cart not_logged_in" href="#cart">
                                    Add to cart <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                        <?php
                    }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
            }  }
    }else{
        ?>
        <h3 style="margin-top:20px">
            Try adding items in the favurite list.
        </h3>
        <?php
        echo $_REQUEST['q'] . " are in the fav list ";
    } 
}else{
        echo "this is not working";
    }         
    ?>
```

This is the part of the AJAX that I have called in a click event:

```
document.querySelector(".fa-shopping-cart").addEventListener("click", function(){
window.location.href = "show_cart.php";
});

document.querySelector(".fa-user-circle").addEventListener("click",function(){
    window.location.href = "user_profile.php";
});

let below_nav = document.querySelectorAll(".childs_of_the_user_detail_nav");

below_nav.forEach(function(elm , i ){
  elm.addEventListener("click",function(){

    if(i == 1 ){
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(localStorage)) {
        let minfied = key.replace("?keyword=", "");
        
        if(isNaN(minfied)){
        }else{
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          // console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "load_fav.php?q=" + minfied, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        document.querySelector(".fav_container_user_page").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }}
      }
  }
    }
    below_nav.forEach(elme =>{
      elme.style.border ="none";
    });
    elm.style.borderBottom = "5px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.802)";
  })
})
```

I am not able to find the bug. Why my code is not working.

I am trying to make a web app this bug is not giving me to working but if I do it without the prepare statement then it works.

Which I think is not good for the security.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @chewie the  error i am getting is nothing it is just not showing any error or any thing even there is the data in the database the num rows gives zero and never goes in the if statement with prepare statement but if i select all without where  in the sql querryit works..

Comment: This will always be false `$result->num_rows > 0`

Comment: Learn to debug! Learn to check values before and/or after you expect them, like `print_r()` or `var_dump()` would be your best friends in PHP....

Comment: once i was working with PHP and Ajax and making for Http request to a server I was stuck on the same problem and i just read the docs and many more article and one article helped me go and check it out..
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given wrong names to your variables. The result of `prepare()` is a prepared statement i.e. object of type `mysqli_stmt`. This is not the result with the data. You must get the result after the execution.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `laptop` WHERE id_no=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$_REQUEST['q']);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
```